# c# windows application GridView Row changing color depending on value

Tags: c#, gridview

i have a filled GridView, what i want is to check the value in an int column called "Points" which right now is filled with Null values , some cells do have value though , that's given by the user.So it's null until it gets a value.

I want the GridView Row to change color when a Points cell gets a value, So with a quick look i can distinguish which is done and which is not!

I have managed to make an example code work for Name column, but when i tried to check for the Points column i failed :S..

here's the code:

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Name")
        {
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                try{
                string stringValue = (string)e.Value;
                stringValue = stringValue.ToLower();
                if ((stringValue.IndexOf("nikos") > -1))
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
                }
                }catch (InvalidCastException  ex){
            }

            }                        
        }           
    }
```

how can i modify it so i can check for the null or int values in the Points column.

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Points")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
             this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
        }                      
    }           
}
```

Just make a check to see if the Points column is null, if its not then set the background colour

Comment: i tried that before and thanks for your answer, but if i do this everything turns red , i suppose e.Value being an object just checks if a cell exists , so everything changes color!